# Adding Post-Processing to Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, glsl, shader, pixi.js

I'm working on a canvas-based heatmap using a library called simpleheat (https://github.com/mourner/simpleheat). I've got the heatmap effect working, but does anyone here know how I'd be able to achieve a glow affect like the image below? I've tried implementing this effect with Pixi filters, but haven't had any luck so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do this manually, or point by point based on xy coordinates for a map that you might have, you could just make a canvas overlay for the map and then draw points on the canvas as overlays. I think you can also set the canvas colors as rgba to make them slightly transparent.

(srry i was gonna make this a comment but i dont have enough reputation for that lol)

hope this helps